# How to Handle error of YouTube Data API v3 quota exceed

Tags: youtube-api

I developed a program using YouTubeDataApi v3.
How I handle an error of quota exceeding?
I found No documentation of actual error message when quota exceeded.
This is difficult that to make full use of quota.

Answer (score 0):

When you decode the json response there will be an error field that reads

```
Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.
```

PHP example catch

```
            $data = json_decode( $response );
            if ( isset( $data->error ) ) {
                    echo 'YouTube returned Error: ' . $data->error->message ;
            }
```